# Как сбросить счетчик номера с начала нового года?

Tags: jpa, hibernate, java, orm

Здравствуйте! Сразу перейду к делу: существует система журналирования в которой каждая запись в журнале имеет свой регистрационный номер(по сути auto_increment). Сейчас появилась необходимость обнулять этот счетчик с наступление нового года, чтобы рег.номер записей был относительно начала года.
Возможно ли сделать это на уровне Hibernate? Возможно ли написать свой sequenceGenerator для этого(поле рег. номера не id!)? Писать триггер не приемлемо.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate поддерживает кастомизацию sequence генератора. Пример [фтыкать здесь](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CustomSequences)

Comment: Дело в том,  что поле требующее сброса не является primary_key. Насколько я понял, написать кастомный sequence генератор можно только для первичного ключа.